# Meteor raix:push: Android Client no longer registering after upgrade

Tags: android, meteor, push-notification

After upgrading from raix:push 2.6.12 to 3.0.0 my Push notifications stopped working on Android.

When I run my app in a browser, the logging (with Push.debug=true) shows:

```
Push: Settings userId "qwertyuiopasdfghj" for app: mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsap
```

When I run my app on Android no such message is shown.

In both cases (logged in on Android or in Browser) when I `Push.send` I get:

```
Push: Send message "blablabla" via query { userId: 'qwertyuiopasdfghj' }
Push: Sent message "blablabla" to 0 ios apps 0 android apps
Push, GUIDE: The "Push.appCollection" is empty - No clients have registred on the server yet...
```

This is intended when logged in on the browser, but not when logged in via the Android app.

The upgrade to Push 3.0.0 included an upgrade from Meteor 1.1 to 1.2 and the inclusion of Crosswalk. Removing Crosswalk didn't help.

What keeps my Android client from registering?

Comment: May be this should work for you,
https://forums.meteor.com/t/raix-push-no-clients-have-registered-on-the-server-yet/20886/6?u=thilak

Comment: Did you find a way for it to work? :) I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090029/android-app-not-registering-with-fcm-when-using-raixpush-package-in-meteor

Comment: I think I downgraded, but that was 3 years ago.

I got in touch with the author here https://github.com/raix/push/issues/127