# Android app not registering with FCM when using raix:push package in Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I want to have Push notifications in different mobile platforms and the browser and decided to use [raix:push](https://github.com/raix/push) for that, which uses [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

I followed the installation steps in [`README.md`](https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/README.md), which worked without problems and the project built and ran fine.

I followed the steps in [`ANDROID.md`](https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/docs/ANDROID.md) and added FCM to my project on https://console.firebase.google.com/ (written down `Sender ID` and `Server key`). Then I created an app on https://play.google.com/apps/publish and linked the `Sender ID` in the `Services & APIs` section.
At this moment I wasn't exactly sure what else to do to make Google aware that my app is authorized to register for FCM. I tried uploading my apk in the `internal test track` channel, so it could see the config and signature in the apk, is that how it works?

Then I added the appropriate `Push.configure` and `App.configurePlugin` calls on the client as well as the `Push.configure` call on the Server.
To help debugging and fix potential problems, from [here](http://%20https://medium.com/@acarabott/meteor-native-ios-push-notifications-heroku-raix-push-cordova-213f486c4e6d) under the Server Code section, I added `Push.debug = true`, `Push.allow(...)` and a `Meteor.methods(...)` for debug output and triggering a notification sent from the server via the Browser console in the client (which according to Server logs is triggered).

On the Server logs, the Push registration seems to have completed (`GCM configured` log output), but on the client, even with `Push.debug = true`, I get no output on whether anything failed or succeeded.
All I know is that the server doesn't get a device which registers and says `Push: Sent message "the title" to 0 ios apps 0 android apps`, when sending a message through the `Meteor.call`.

Did I forget a step for properly registering my app with FCM and how can I further debug my problem?